# Using XCode Instruments Time Profiler with optimization enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, profiling, instruments

I'm doing some number crunching in C++, and I'm seeing a vast difference in CPU % usage when using `-Os` optimization in my Debug build. I would therefore like to profile my code with optimizations enabled, so that I don't waste time optimizing code that the compiler already optimizes well.

When I try to profile with `-Os` optimization, I can't get Instruments to symbolicate my code (even when I manually specify the location of my `.dSYM` file). It won't even show my top-level C++ member functions that are not templated or inlined.

I can get it to symbolicate fine when I specify the default `-O0` optimization level.

So, is it even possible to profile with optimizations enabled? If so, then what's the trick to make it work?

I'm using XCode 4.3.3.

Comment: A comment I have is that generally, as a programmer, you're going to be optimising at a higher level than the compiler, e.g. using the correct data structures, lazy loading or whatever, whereas the compiler is going to be inlining methods, unrolling loops etc.  So I don't think you're wasting your time optimising with compiler optimisation turned off, you're not going to be optimising the same kinds of things as the compiler.

Comment: @JonoB: Consider this scenario (which is close to mine). Before optimization, in my innermost loop, `StepA()` takes 100ms and `StepB()` takes 100ms. After optimization, `StepA()` takes 10ms and `StepB()` takes 50ms. Without profiling information with optimizations enabled, how am I supposed to know that I should focus my efforts on `StepB()`.

Comment: What compiler/xcode version are you using? I often profile with -Os or higher (in a release build).

Comment: @EmileCormier I guess you can't really know that.  In my experience with profiling, it's often pretty clear where a bottleneck is, compiler optimisations or not, but obviously this isn't always going to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time Profiler did indeed symbolicate when using `-Os`. The optimizer did it's job so well, that my C++ DSP code got inlined and speeded up to the point where the profiler would not sample any of it in the short amount of time that I let it run. All I could see in the call tree were system calls.

When I tried running the profiler for longer, the profiler caught a few blips of my DSP code. It only showed my top-level DSP function called by some NSOperationQueue handler. The rest underneath seemed to be all inlined.

I got more useful results when I compiled with `-O2`. More of my DSP subroutines were left intact (instead of being inlined), so I was better able to gauge where my DSP algorithm was spending its time. But all that is moot, because now I can see that the app is spending vastly more time in housekeeping system calls than in my DSP code.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be an edit to my question, rather than an answer.

Comment: I think this is useful enough for other people hitting the same problem that answering yourself is fine. Compiler optimisations make such a huge difference nowadays that profiling is so more difficult than it used to be.